# one page works but another gets: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, debugging, typeerror

I have two webpages with the same table on them so I wrote a script to allow easy modification of both. The script works perfectly on one page but on the other it gets an Uncaught TypeError cannot read property 'length' of undefined on line 18.

```
var i, j, dat, lnk, txt;
var pak1, pak3, pak2;

lnk = ''; //Just a long string
lnk += '';

pak1 = ["1 GB","50 kr","30 dagar","",lnk];
pak2 = ["3 GB","100 kr","30 dagar","",lnk];
Pak3 = ["10 GB","200 kr","30 dagar","",lnk];

dat = [pak1, pak2, pak3];

txt = '<table class="table table-striped detail-info"><tbody><tr><td class="title-col"><h5>Data</h5></td>';
txt += '<td><h5>Cost</h5></td><td>Limit</td><td></td><td></td></tr>';

for(i = 0; i < dat.length; i++){
    txt += '<tr>';
    for(j = 0; j < dat[i].length; j++){//Error occurs here
        if(j === 0){
            txt += '<td class="title-col">' + dat[i][j] + '</td>';
        }else{
            txt += '<td>' + dat[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
    }
    txt += '</tr>';
}

txt += '</tbody></table>';

document.getElementById("infoTable").innerHTML = txt;
```

I use the same html on both pages to load the script and they are located in the same folder.

```
<!-- SCRIPT -->
<div id="infoTable"></div>
<script src="./script/infoTable.js"></script>
<!-- END SCRIPT -->
```

I don't have alot of experience with JavaScript so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your example, `Pak3` where you want `pak3`

Comment: It was the typo screwing it all up. I feel like an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: @OskarAdolfsson No worries, it happens to us all. Sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes. :)